# How to estimate RAM required to load tensorflow model in CPU?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

I am observing my dnn model (model size: 400 mb including pb file + variables dir) is consuming 1G memory when I load the model with tensorflow serving.

So I am wondering is there a way to estimate the RAM size before I actually load the model. I assumed the model size can be equal to the RAM size, and also curious why I see the size difference between model size and RAM usage.

I am using tensorflow 1.15 model with tensorflow serving 2.3

Thank you!

Comment: Simple answer is no. It is not depend on the size of the model, or the number of params in the model. However, you can estimate it if you know exactly the structure of the model (CNN or RNN or something else, how many hidden nodes in each layer, ...)

Comment: Can you take a look at this [section](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/profiler#memory_profile_summary) from `Tensorflow Profiler`, which helps you to understand the memory profile for your tensorflow program. Let us know if that is what you're looking for. Thanks!